# How to test a React Native component that imports a custom native module with Jest?

Tags: ios, facebook, unit-testing, react-native, jestjs

Here is a simple component that I am trying to test using React Native 0.39 and Jest 18:

```
// index.ios.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, NativeModules, View } from 'react-native';

export default class TestProject extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    NativeModules.TestModule.test();
  }

  render() {
    return <View style={{ flex: 1 }} />;
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('TestProject', () => TestProject);
```

Here is TestModule and its `test` method:

```
// ios/TestProject/TestModule.m

#import "TestModule.h"

@implementation TestModule

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE();

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(test){
  NSLog(@"This is a test");
}

@end
```

The following test fails with the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined`:

```
// __tests__/index.ios.js

import 'react-native';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import React from 'react';
import Index from '../index.ios.js';

it('renders correctly', () => {
  const tree = renderer.create(
    <Index />
  );
});
```

I have read the Jest docs on how to [Mock native modules using jest.mock](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-react-native.html#mock-native-modules-using-jestmock), but am still unclear as to how to extend Jest's mock of NativeModules to include my TestModule class above.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can simply add a mock where your native module should be:

```
import {
  NativeModules,
} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';

describe('TestProject', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    NativeModules.TestModule = { test: jest.fn() } 
  });
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thanks! The function passed into `beforeEach` is missing a closing curly brace, but otherwise works like a charm. I also chose to use `beforeAll` instead, because this setup needs only to be run once, rather than before each spec.

Comment: Great, and I added the missing curly brace.

Comment: It fails now (0.57), because you cannot add property to read-only object

Answer (score 13):

This way, you will mock it once (before jest starts)

`jest.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'react-native',
  setupFiles: ['./__mocks__/your-native-bridge.js']
};
```

`__mocks__/your-native-bridge.js`

```
import {NativeModules} from 'react-native';

NativeModules.YourNativeBridge = {
  property: jest.fn()
};
```

Don't forget to mock all possible functions, properties in `YourNativeBridge`

Comment: Has anyone written a full list of these properties?  I'm not sure which ones I need, so I guess all of them will do

Answer (score 2):

Jest is a JavaScript testing tool, it won't run code that you have written in Objective C/Swift/Java in a native module. You can mock the functionality of a native module so that you can call it from JavaScript by the approach you linked to. eg.

```
jest.mock('NetInfo', () => {
  return {
    isConnected: {
      fetch: () => {
        return new Promise((accept, resolve) => {
          accept(true);
        })
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I think this misunderstands the question, which I also have. The OP is asking how you mock `NativeModules.TestModule` which is imported from `react-native`. I'm stuck since `react-native` needs to be imported, not mocked, for the `react-test-renderer` overrides to work.

Comment: @rgoldfinger is correct. I am not trying to test the native module itself but trying to mock `NativeModules.TestModule` in order to test `index.ios.js`.

Comment: Is there a way to test the native module?

Answer (score 0):

```
#__mocks__/react-native-modules

const ReactNative = require('react-native')

ReactNative.NativeModules = {
  Defaults: {
    RU: {
      publicKey: '',
      privateKey: '',
    },
  },
}

module.exports = ReactNative
```

and then

```
# in test file
jest.mock('react-native-modules')
import 'react-native-modules'
```

Comment: this fails with: "Cannot set property NativeModules of #<Object> which has only a getter"

Answer (score 0):

This failed for me, too (react-native 0.57.5, jest 23.6.0). I was able to find a solution, but it was totally different (and in my case, a more elegant fix) than here.

Check out [the ticket I filed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53510385/jest-error-when-trying-to-import-native-modules-unable-to-prevent-with-mock) for more details.

Essentially, I had to have NativeModules fleshed out by a function passed as the second parameter to [jest.mock()](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) and put this is in a script run at the beginning of each test using Jest's [setupFiles](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfiles-array) config option.