# jest testing of method using native module

Tags: javascript, react-native, unit-testing, jestjs, ts-jest

I am trying to create an unit test for my function.
Below the method "requestAuthorization" is a method in swift and i am invoking it through RN's Native Modules.
I get this error "**Cannot read property 'requestAuthorization' of undefined**"
If the method runs successfully it resolves back a string "Authorized Successfully!"
How can i test this????

**index.ts (my method "requestAuthorization" is defined here)**

```
const requestAuthorization = (
  read: [],
  write: [] = []
): Promise<boolean> => {

  const readAuth = read.reduce((obj, cur) => {
    return { ...obj, [cur]: true };
  }, {});

  const writeAuth = write.reduce((obj, cur) => {
    return { ...obj, [cur]: true };
  }, {});

  return NativeModules.MyHealthLibrary.requestAuthorization(writeAuth, readAuth);
};

const HealthKit = {
  requestAuthorization
}

export default HealthKit;
```

Now in my test.js

```
import { type } from '../authTypes';
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

jest.mock('react-native', () => {
    return {
        NativeModules: {
            MyHealthLibrary: {
                requestAuthorization: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve())
            }
          }
        }
    })

const utils = jest.createMockFromModule('../index.ts').default;

utils.requestAuthorization = jest.fn((read, write) => {
    return NativeModules.MyHealthLibrary.requestAuthorization(read, write)    
});


test('healthkit permissions', () => {

        expect(utils.requestAuthorization.mock).toBeTruthy();

        let read = [type.heartRate]
        let write = [type.heartRate]
        expect(read).toEqual(["HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate"])
        expect(write).toEqual(["HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate"])

        await utils.requestAuthorization(read, write).then(result => {
                console.log("result:",result) //ALWAYS UNDEFINED
            })
});
```

**UPDATE:** 
In my swift method "requestAuthorization", it resolves a string "Authorized Successfully!".

```
jest.mock('../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/NativeModules', () => ({
    MyHealthLibrary: {
      requestAuthorization: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve())
    },
  }));


 test('healthkit permissions', async() => {

            let read = [type.heartRate]
            let write = [type.heartRate]
            expect(read).toEqual(["HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate"])
            expect(write).toEqual(["HKQuantityTypeIdentifierHeartRate"])

            let result = await NativeModules.MyHealthLibrary.requestAuthorization(read, write)
                console.log("result:",result)   
//NOT PRINTING "Authorized Successfully!" INSTEAD PRINTING "undefined"
       
    });
```

Comment: You need to mock NativeModules in the first place, Node isn't a device it's supposed to run on. The test doesn't make sense because you only test the code you wrote above, createMockFromModule creates a stub.

Comment: I have updated my question. please check now.

Comment: Mock NativeModules according to your expectations, that's it. Do not mock a module you're testing.

Comment: i am confused. could you please elaborate. sorry this is the first time i am working with NativeModules and Jest.

Comment: Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53510385/jest-error-when-trying-to-import-native-modules-unable-to-prevent-with-mock

Comment: Thanks man. Please check my UPDATES in my question. the swift method resolves a string "Authorized Successfully!". Thats what i want to test. whether my method sends back the string. But i seem to get "undefined" :\ my NativeModule method not working?? It works fine when i test it on my app's front-end. I get the string "Authorized Successfully!".

Comment: You mocked requestAuthorization to return a promise of undefined, so it returns undefined. As I said, mock it according to your expectations. Return Promise.resolve("Authorized Successfully!") if that's what you expect. Afaik the mock should be `jest.mock('NativeModules', ...)` instead of full path, but I can't confirm.

Comment: ok. So i NEED to mock the NativeModule method for it to work. There is no way of accessing the NativeModule method without mocking it? Why doesn't a direct call "await NativeModules.MyHealthLibrary.requestAuthorization" work?

Comment: NativeModule is native, as the name implies. It's supposed to be compiled for a platform you're running the app on. Jests tests run in Node.js, not on a device.